# Vim syntax files - Ignore line prefix

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

I have files containing code within a prefix-based structure, such as:

```
perl: sub abc {
perl:     return "def";
perl: }
```

I'd like to be able to highlight the perl as normal. i.e. ignore the `perl:` prefix. Using the built-in help for syntax I have:

```
syntax include @Perl syntax/perl.vim
syntax region testPerl start=/^perl: \?/ end=/$/ contains=testPerlContinue,@Perl
syntax match testPerlContinue "\$perl:" contained
```

However, as expected, this treats the `perl:` prefix as part of the code; an obvious example of this breaking is where a Perl `'quote'` carries over several lines.

Is it possible to ignore prefixes within Vim when syntax highlighting?

Comment: It is very unlikely this will be easy, if it's even possible. For example, if you look at the perl.vim syntax file you'll find at least a few patterns that "anchor" to the beginning of the line.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the anchoring problem. It certainly indicates it's not possible. The alternative is to pre-process the file into regions more conducive to syntax highlighting, then post-process it back to the original format. I'd ideally like to avoid that for the 'simple' task of editing a file though.